# Showing database in ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am new to android and after going through many tutorials I still can't get things.

I have created a database and is now reading this database.
This database and 3 columns All three string type.

Now I want to show this database using ListView.I have this `ListView`
created with id "`listDatabaseItems`" in `R.layout.viewDatabase`

Currently my code is:

```
Cursor c = sqliteDatabase.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

int firstNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex("name_column");
int protectedColumn = c.getColumnIndex("protected_id_column");

ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0;

c.moveToFirst();
do {
    i++;
    String firstName = c.getString(firstNameColumn);
    String protectedID = c.getString(protectedColumn);
    results.add(firstName + protectedID); // NEED TO add here 
} while (c.moveToNext()); 

sqliteDatabase.close();
```

Please tell me what changes I do and how can I show my database in ListView.

Best Regards.

Comment: Please mention properly that what problem you are facing...?

Comment: My code is missing details, how to link result array to my ListView.

Comment: I think you are facing problem in iterating through the cursor...??

Comment: no, i just want to know how to use ListView to show what is stored in cursor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `Adapter` add your `ListArray` values to it, and then `setAdapter` to your listview simple,

After your code, add just two lines,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also, your question sounds basic for android So just look at these links..

[SimpleCursorAdapters and ListViews](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

[Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

[Filling the Layout with Data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html)

Comment: The syntax is wrong with this. It ain't accepting results. you sure ArrayAdapter<Comment>?

Comment: `mListView.setAdapter(adapter);` (where mListView is an instance of a listview, rather than the ListView class) -- or, if you're in a subclass of `ListActivity`, you can use `getListView().setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked but how can i list data into different columns instead of listing them into one line?

Comment: Welcome buddy, Look at [Multicolumn ListView in Android](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/).. Its for multicolumn listview..

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Cursor in the first place, I'd actually go with a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).  A CursorAdapter allows you to avoid loading the whole data set into memory, making initial load times faster and avoiding huge allocations with large data sets.

To expand on the basic setup in this post ([SimpleCursorAdapters and ListViews](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)), You'll also want to set a view binder to customize the way data is bound to the view, ie. concatenate your two strings.

Something like this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
          //you're only using one view, so we can ignore columnIndex
          TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);

          //the cursor is already in position for this list item
          int firstNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex("name_column");
          int protectedColumn = c.getColumnIndex("protected_id_column");
          String firstName = c.getString(firstNameColumn);
          String protectedID = c.getString(protectedColumn);
          text.setText(firstName+protectedID);
          return true; //we have handled binding the data
      }
 };
```

Then when you set up your adapter, you pass it a layout that can be used for each item. The layout should contain a TextView to hold the one text item you want to show.  You may be able to use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` for this as user370305 suggested, but I'm not sure what the id of its TextView is -- it might be `android.R.id.text1`.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    context,           //can be your Activity 
    R.layout.list_item,  //xml layout containing textview with id 'list_item_text'
    c,                 //the cursor
    new String[] {"name_column"}, //the column to read (we'll do more in the binder)
    new int[] {R.id.list_item_text}, //the view to hold the data
    0 //no flags
);
adapter.setViewBinder(binder);
```

Add it to your ListView the same way:

```
ListView listView = //your ListView reference
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//or in a ListActivity:
setListAdapter(adapter);
```